# How to Apply jQuery to Elements Not Available at Document.Ready?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

The website I am developing uses [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) to [load content via AJAX](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax) (in this case, each tab is made up of a partial page). This works well, and I am happy with those results. However, one problem I have repeatedly come across is that when I include jQuery within my master.js file (which I use for site-wide Javascript), it DOES NOT apply to anything that is loaded in via AJAX. For example, I tried something simple like:

```
// Theme all the buttons with jQuery UI themes.
$('input:button').button();
```

However, all the buttons on the tabs are not themed appropriately.

How do I fix this? I was thinking something with [jQuery's .live() function](http://api.jquery.com/live/), but both the 'load' and the 'ready' events don't appear to be working. This has become a pretty frustrating problem so any help that can be provided would be most appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some of the code that you are having problems with? Using live or delegate is most likely the way to go, but not all event handlers will need to be bound using live or delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply it to those new elements in your AJAX callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/some/path',
    success: function( resp ) {
        var $newElements = $(resp);  //create jQuery object of new elements
        $newElements.find('input:button').button();  // call .button() on inputs
        $newElements.appendTo('body');  // append to wherever
    }
});
```

I have no idea what is happening in your AJAX callback, but this should give you the general idea.

Comment: This worked, although I needed to use the callback via the jQueryUI tabs 'load' function (which is called after each tab loads). See more here (for anybody who is interested): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740652/jquery-ui-tabs-callback-after-ajax-loading-a-tab

Answer (score 1):

Well, the livequery plugin ( http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery ) used to be used for a lot of stuff like this.  It's not the most efficient way to handle the problem, though.

If you're adding content via AJAX, why not just re-assign handlers for the content after you add it?

```
// setup simple jQuery plugin to handle all of your custom logic (although this could be a normal function as well)
$.fn.assignMyHandlers = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).find('input:button').button();
        // etc
    });
};

// and then everywhere that you bring in AJAX'd content...
$.get('test.html', function( html ) {
    var $fragment = $( html );
    $fragment.assignMyHandlers();
    $fragment.appendTo( "#theList" );
});
```