# How do I bind appended html with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm loading HTML content and appending this to a DIV. The problem then of course, is that the HTML is not bound.

Since I'm not clicking anything, I can't use `jQuery.live` or `jQuery.bind` (I think).

Here is my code.

```
// Load directory content and display list
  function loadDirContent(current_path,new_dir)
  {  
    // Load new content in browser window
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../wp-content/plugins/wp-filebrowser/fileBrowser.php",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {current_path: current_path, new_dir: new_dir},

        success: function(html){
                 jQuery("#fileBrowser").html(html); // Append new content
        }
    });  
  }
```

How can I bind this new HTML so that I may run jQuery on the added content?

I face the problem when I use the Ajax Upload Plugin. It fetches data from the form, but any $_POST data is left blank. This occurs only after "page reload" using my loadDirContent function.

**UPDATE**

I have the following input in my form:
    relative_url; ?>" />
Each time I go one directory down in my file browser, `current_path` is updated.

[Ajax File Upload Plugin](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/) calls the `uploader.php` function. Inside uploader.php I have the following command: `$this->current_path   = $_POST['current_path'];`

The problem is that `$_POST['current_path']` is empty.

Comment: Just a thought: you can `jQuery("#fileBrowser").html(html);` instead of `empty()` and `append()`.

Comment: What do you mean 'the HTML is not bound'?  What event of what object do you want to bind to?

Comment: @B: Thanks. One instruction less :)

Comment: @E: I have made a file browser interface. When I click a new folder, the entire interface is reloaded, thus fetching new HTML. This isdone using jQuery. But when I append this data to the DIV, the Ajax Uplaoder plugin is not able to fetch all data inside the form. Therefore I think it's becauase new content is not bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$().live and $().delegate will both work on events other than click.  What event are you binding handlers to?

Additionally, if live/delegate really won't work, you can always bind handlers within the success callback.

---

Example:

```
// function for doing event binding:
function bindHandlers(root) {
    // do any event binding here, only selecting elements within the provided root
    $('.something', root).click(...);
    $('.something-else', root).hover(..., ...);
};

// bind all children of the document on dom ready
$(function() { bindHandlers(document); });

// Load directory content and display list
function loadDirContent(current_path,new_dir)
{  
  // Load new content in browser window
  jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../wp-content/plugins/wp-filebrowser/fileBrowser.php",
      dataType: 'html',
      data: {current_path: current_path, new_dir: new_dir},

      success: function(html){
          // append the new stuff and attach handlers
          bindHandlers($('#fileBrowser').html(html));
      }
  });  
}
```

Comment: how would you bind it on success callback?

Comment: I added an example... it creates a general purpose function that will attach handlers to elements within a given root element.  On dom load, you run it against the document, and on successful ajax operations, you run it against the new markup.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the solutions I received [in my recent, similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677639/how-to-apply-jquery-to-elements-not-available-at-document-ready). Both are good answers (I marked the one that helped me). From the looks of what you're doing, you'll probably want to re-assign handlers for the content after you add it.